# Why when I send an attachment through a Python program the attachment don't arrive to the destination account?

Tags: python, gmail, email-attachments

I am using the next code to send an attachment through Python:

```
            message = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
            message['to'] = cliente.email
            message['from'] = remitente
            message['subject'] = "Solicitud en retroalimentacion".decode("utf-8")
            html = ""
            with open(html_send, 'r') as fichero:
                html =fichero.read()
                part1 = MIMEText('Vexi', 'plain')
                part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html', "utf-8")
                message.attach(part1)
                message.attach(part2)
                main_type, sub_type = content_type.split('/', 1)
                print("main_type - " + str(main_type))
                print("sub_type - " + str(sub_type))
                print("file - " + str(file))
                fp = open(file, 'rb')
                attachment = MIMEBase(main_type, sub_type)
                attachment.set_payload(fp.read())
                fp.close()
                encode_base64(attachment)
                attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment;filename=attachment.pdf')
                message.attach(attachment)
                byte_msg = message.as_string().encode(encoding="UTF-8")
                byte_msg_b64encoded = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(byte_msg)
                str_msg_b64encoded = byte_msg_b64encoded.decode(encoding="UTF-8")
                msg = {'raw': str_msg_b64encoded}
```

I review the sent mails of the origin account and it has the attachment file, but on the inbox of the destination account I only received the body of the email without the attachment file (pdf).

Do you have any idea why it does not arrive?

Comment: Have you tried to send the file to non-gmail mailbox?

Comment: Yes, I tried to send the email to non-gmail mailbox, it is the same behavior, I receive the body of the message, but don't the attachement file.